# Keep getting dereferencing NULL pointer error when using linked list

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, null, singly-linked-list

I am trying to find a string in my linked list(Its location is determined by an integer starting at 1) and move it to the front of the list. I have not put in the move to the front of the list code yet, as I have not been able to deal with this error.

```
typedef struct node NODE;
struct node
{
    char word[WORDSIZE];    
    struct node* next;      
};

NODE* start;


int add_to_list(NODE** start, char data[])
{

    NODE* new;
    NODE* curr;

    curr = *start;

    if ((new = malloc(sizeof(NODE))) == NULL)
        return -1;

    strcpy_s(new->word, WORDSIZE, data);
    new->next = *start;
    *start = new;

    return 0;
} 

void FindPrintMove(NODE* start, int index) {
    int size = 0;
    NODE* cur = start;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        size++;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    cur = start;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < (size - index)) {
        cur = cur->next;
    
    }
    printf("%s", cur->word);
}
```

I feel like I could use a doubly linked list or add to the end instead of the start but i dont think that would solve this issue

Comment: Please update your code to me a [mre].  This includes headers and a main that illustrate the error.

Comment: Tag it with windows or whatever platform you are on (for support of `strcpy_s()`).

Comment: Is it a linked list where you add things to the end or a reverse linked list where you add stuff to the front?

Comment: `curr = *start;` - this is an indication of that you _know_ what needs to be done - but, you are not using `curr` anywhere. You don't need to either, but still, there is a reason you take `NODE** start` as an argument.

Comment: If you're getting such an error from the constraint handler on account of the call to `strcpy_s()` in `add_to_list()`, then that presumably means that the `data` pointer passed into `add_to_list()` is null.  I am guessing that it is the constraint handler flagging the issue because it seems to be specifically recognizing a null pointer dereference, as opposed to blindly attempting the derference and crashing with a low-level error.

Comment: Using a debugger and stepping through this program is probably the best way to find out where it goes awry.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what is the purpose of this while loop

```
while (i < (size - index)) {
    cur = cur->next;

}
```

but within it the variable `i` is not being changed. So you have an infinite loop that will be broken when the tail of the list will be achieved and a null pointer will be dereferenced.

Pay attention to that positions in the list should start from 0.

Comment: It was to find the item in the list which is indicated by the argument index, I updated my list so it adds to the end and I changed my code to this and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
void FindPrintMove(NODE* start, int index) {
    int size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    NODE* cur = start;

    while (size < index) {
        cur = cur->next;
        size++;
        //printf("%s ", cur->word);
    }
    printf("%d", size);
    cur = start;
    while (i < size) {
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    printf("%s", cur->word);
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).